# Problemas para cargar archivos con jQuery, Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

He intentado cargar documentos a mi servidor de forma distinta a como lo hemos trabajado anteriormente.
Ya que lo haciamos por HTML encriptando un acction en el form pero ya no me llama tanto la atencion de esa forma

he intentado usar Ajax para mandar los datos pero me manda mensajes de null o que no encuentra el nombre del archivo

use vardump para intentar ver el documento si realmente llegaba a php y efectivamente no lo encuentra
declare las variables en varias ocaciones diferentes y sigue sin funcionar, quisiera que me pudieran apoyar

```
    introducir el código aquí

<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" >
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" id='archvioID' name="archvioID">
  <input type="button" id="subir" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Cargar">
</div>

</form>
```

```html
<script>
   $('#subir').on('click',function(){
        var miArchvio = $("#archvioID").prop('files')[0];
         var data = new FormData();
         data.append('archvioID-'[0],miArchvio);
       console.log(miArchvio)

           $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              cache:false,
              contetType: false,
              processData:false,
             data: data,
              method: 'POST',
              url:"php/valida_carga_server.php",
             
           }).done(function(respuesta){
               alert(respuesta)
           })
     
    });
    </script>
```

```
    introducir el código aquí
<?php


// exit(var_dump($_FILES));
   if (isset($_FILES['archvioID-[0]'])) {
        //echo "si llego";
       $archivo = $_FILES["archvioID-[0]"]["name"];
       $Carpeta = "../Formatos/";
       $accion= move_uploaded_file($archivo,$Carpeta.$archivo);
       if ($accion) {
           echo "exito";
       }
       else{
        echo "No se subio el archivo";
       }
       
   }
  else{
      echo "No hay datos";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formulario debería tener esta entrada para permitir la carga del form para imágenes y documentos que provengan de un

```
<form class="form_example" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

el script tiene que poner dentro de una variable el FormData del formulario
y enviarlo con el $.ajax(), con contentType: false, y processData: falsa tambien

```
<script>
    var formData_example = new FormData($(".form_example")[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: "./php/valida_carga_server.php",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData_example,
    })
</script>
```

y en el PHP puedes recibir el $_FILE[] como una matriz de datos como mismo si enviaran el objeto mediante un submit por defecto del formulario

```
<?PHP   
    //datos del arhivo
    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        
    //compruebo si las características del archivo son las que deseo
    if (!((strpos($tipo_archivo, "gif") || strpos($tipo_archivo, "jpeg")) && ($tamano_archivo < 100000))) {
        echo "La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],  $nombre_archivo)){
                echo "El archivo ha sido cargado correctamente.";
        } else {
                echo "Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Bro!! mme sorprendes solucionaste mi problema al 100% lo acople nada mas a como me funciona mejor y quedo perfecto, jaja al menos ya puede mover documentos a la misma carpeta del codigo pero ahora solo me falta direccionarlo,, eres un maestro bro !

Comment: Gracias Bro!! son años de estudio. Si con direccionarlos te refieres a poner en otra carpeta la imagen que subiste es así. En ese caso la misma funciona move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], ./url/donde/lo/necesitas/$nombre_archivo) así colocas la imagen donde la necesites en tu sistemas de directorio dentro de tu server

Comment: ya me quedo bro! , muchas gracias